# Searching the xpath in html code, highlights the exact path which is need, but inside the code it is not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception, nosuchelementexception

Here is the exception I am getting while running the  code:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(.,'STEP3 Orientation')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.110)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [3b7c5c64e8bf5a509fa70a6b5f095c21, findElement {using=xpath, value=//span[contains(.,'STEP3 Orientation')]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 115.0.5790.110, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f..., userDataDir: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61749}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:61749/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 115.0.5790.110, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 3b7c5c64e8bf5a509fa70a6b5f095c21
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:350)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at Selenium.Demo1.main(Demo1.java:30)


I am trying to fetch the details using the following xpath:
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'STEP3 Orientation')]")).getText();
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'pageTitle')]")).getText();
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'STEP3 Orientation')]")).getText();
```

For all 3 xpath, I am getting the NoSuchElementException

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VemoF.png)
[Searching the xpath in html code, highlights the exact path which is need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj0GR.png)
Searching the xpath in html code, highlights the exact path which is need, but inside the code it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying selenium's [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/). Below code uses `ExplicitWait` to locate the desired element:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'STEP3 Orientation')]"))).getText();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'pageTitle')]"))).getText();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'STEP3 Orientation')]"))).getText();
```

Imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped to solve the issue.